# Can you overwrite nested views in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Hopefully I can explain this question sufficiently.
I would like the "login" page to have it's own html that is not wrapped with the same code as the protected pages (things like topbar, menu,etc).
How does one go about doing that. 
I have app.component in which the template is

```
<topbar></topbar>
<div id="wrapper">
    <menu></menu>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This is great for all the protected pages (the entire app except the login page), but the login page renders like this:

```
<my-app>
    <topbar><!-- topbar html code --></topbar>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <menu><!-- menu html code --></menu>
        <login><!-- login html code --></login>
        ...
    </div>
</my-app>
```

How do I do something like:

```
<my-app>
    <login><!-- login html code --></login>
    <!-- no extra code -->
</my-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have the top-level `app.component` act as a "routing" component, which has two routes. The first route is the `login.component` then the second route is the standard shell of the app.

```
<my-app>
    <router>outlet></router-outlet>
</my-app>
```

Then when the app is loaded, you'd get your login that would render similar to this:

```
<my-app>
    <router>outlet></router-outlet>
    <login>
       ...
    </login>
</my-app>
```

Then after a successful login, `router.navigate` to the shell:

```
<my-app>

    <router>outlet></router-outlet>
    <topbar><!-- topbar html code --></topbar>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <menu><!-- menu html code --></menu>
    ...
</my-app>
```

If I'm understanding this correctly, that should work. The other thing that comes to mind is the `<ng-content></ng-content>`. This allows you to render HTML and components within the markup of another.

Comment: Where would I have `<topbar><!-- topbar html code --></topbar>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <menu><!-- menu html code --></menu>` put? For example:
I feel like I would have to put this code in all pages. Where I need this to act more like a "master template". Does that make sense?